# How to get the lowest value in an ArrayList without using 'comparable'

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Here is my array

```
 ArrayList cars = new ArrayList();
    cars.add(new vehicles ("CAR","Peugot","3008",12500.00));
    cars.add(new vehicles ("CAR","BMW","316",4995.00));
    cars.add(new vehicles ("CAR","Ford","Fiesta",2995.00));
```

and i want a way to put these in order from cheapest first but i dont want to use a compare method. Maybe create a temporary variable and check this variable with the values and overwrite the values if theyre cheaper.

Ive tried this

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList carsArray = new ArrayList();
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("CAR","Peugot","3008",12500.00));
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("CAR","BMW","316",4995.00));
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("CAR","Ford","Fiesta",2995.00));


    vehicles lowestPrice = (vehicles) carsArray.get(0);
    for(vehicles car : carsArray){
        if(car.Cost<lowestPrice.Cost){
            lowestPrice = car;
        }
    }

}
```

Yet i still get a mistake :/The 'carsArray' in the forloop is underlined in red

Comment: Sure. What happened when you tried the approach you mentioned?

Comment: i dont want to use a comparator to be honest, is there another way ?

Comment: You're going to end up using the same logic as `Collections.sort` (or some other sorting algorithm) and `Comparator`.

Comment: Just use exactly what you say : use temp `Car` which remember current lowest and iterate thru your arrayList. This is strange way of doing it, but will work.

Comment: @AJ_91 or better yet keep lowest price index.

Comment: i understand the logic of it but how would i write it out in code ? :/ i know i could use a for loop and go through the array but i dont know how id iterate through the arrayList

Comment: iterate thru arraylist : `for (vehicles car : cars) { //..use your car }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Car lowestPrice = cars.get(0);
for(Car car : cars) {
   if(car.price<lowestPrice.price) {
       lowestPrice = car;
   }
}
```

Concerning the red underlined ArrayList ... replace it with

```
ArrayList<Vehicles> yourlist = new ArrayList<Vehicles>();
```

Comment: how would i implement this into my code? Im a noob so i dont understand this fully. Im getting a mistake. The 'Car'is underlined in red

Comment: @AJ_91 `Car` would be `vehicles` in your case. Btw, class names should start with a capital letter (e.g. `Vehicles`) and since the class seems to represent a _single_ vehicle, it might better be named `Vehicle`.

Comment: ive added some code to my question if you have a chance to view it :)

Comment: I updated my answer... btw it won't take us ages to find solutions if you were telling us WHAT error there is instead of just telling us there is an error. A stacktrace is worth a thousand words.

Comment: it works :)) much appreciated and sorry for the late reply. bank holiday weekend and all that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a TreeMap with the price as the key and the vehicles object as the value. It would then be sorted by price, and you would have all of the information for the vehicle as the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use approach you mentioned in OP you can declare `static` variable for `vehicles` class and in `contructor`  you can check whether price is lower than actual minimum 
**But my advice is to use `Comparator` or `Comparable` because this is their natural use. Also values of objects can be changed throughout various `set` methods and you will have to be aware of that**

If you still want to do it .You do it like this

`public static int min_price=Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

then in `contructor` method
`if(price<min_price)min_price=price;`

Answer (score 0):

As you want to sort the items of the list you can use the `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` method and provide own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
class VechiclePriceComparator implements Comparator<vechiles> {

  public int compare(vechiles v1, vechiles v2) {

    if(v1 == v2) {
       return 0;
    )

    return Double.compare(v1.getPrice(),v2.getPrice());

  }

}
```